# Inner products on abelian groups and general modules

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, modules, inner-product

Where can I find a discussion about inner products on something more general than vector spaces, and to which extent should one attempt such a generalization?

My particular interest is in abelian groups (specifically, the representation ring of a finite group, as described [on *MO*](https://mathoverflow.net/a/2808/57127)). The only references in this case seem to be *Distance-Regular Graphs* by Brower, Cohen and Neumaier (1989), [p. 72](https://books.google.fr/books?id=v6brCAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA72&dq=inner%20product%20on%20abelian%20group%20-character%20-representation&pg=PA72#v=onepage&q&f=false), which does provide a construction for finite groups (contingent on their classification, or so it seems), but no connection to the field case, and *λ-Rings and the Representation Theory of the Symmetric Group* by Knutson (1973), which only concerns itself with the representation ring. (See also [this post](http://at.yorku.ca/cgi-bin/bbqa?forum=ask_an_algebraist_2013&task=show_msg&msg=3483) on *Ask an Algebraist* about the former book.) I would like to see how it fits with the usual inner products over $\mathbf R$ and $\mathbf C$.

> This is a copy of [this question of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2096509/) on *MSE*, which appears to have gone largely unnoticed.

Comment: What do you actually want to know? If $G$ is abelian then an "inner product" on $G$ could just be thought of as an isomorphism from $G$ to its dual. But I don't really see a maths question here. You can make any definition you like but the proof of the pudding is in the eating (is that a UK expression??)

Comment: The choice of the target of the inner product is already not clear. Of course you can map into the base ring, but there are other natural choices (e.g, for a local ring, the injective hull of its residual field; in the case of $\mathbb{Z}$, $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$, etc).

Comment: @Kevin Thus (reference-request): I’m searching for a unified treatment of inner products on the different kinds of stuff one can apparently define them on, the choice of stuff being motivated by the “eating” of a meaningful set of theorems. (Re: choosing $\hat G \cong G$, yes, a general description of duality would be another way to put it—but I don’t know how to make it include the representation ring example. It is funny, though, how the $\hat G \cong G$ description *automatically* yields that the target of the product for finite groups is $\mathbf Z/e\mathbf Z$.)

Comment: @YCor Well, it could be that there is no unique general theory. I’m only trying to figure out if anyone actually cared enough to pose the question.